# Synchronize CefSharp render and WPF render

Tags: c#, wpf, synchronization, webgl, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp in WPF application in offscreen-mode.

Inside browser WebGL 3D model. At some points of model must be "billboard" but it must be WPF object in 2D space of WPF.

At each frame render I calculate projection of 3D point to 2D screen coords and send callback to WPF with 2D coords.

Visually 2D object of WPF moved on 1-2 frame faster than 3D model. It's  strange because I'm catching onRender event of CEF and set billboards coords after browser render.

How I can synchronize render of 3D model and 2D billboards in WPF?

Answer (score 1):

The culprit may be the fact that a WPF application does not have a predictable refresh rate. It redraws the UI based on under-the-hood heuristics influenced by your hardware and the current state of the OS. WPF cannot be forced to redraw at will unless you work around it with DirectDraw. Read in more detail here: https://rhnatiuk.wordpress.com/2008/12/21/wpf-video-playback-problems/

If you have continuous motion rendering within a WPF application, such as video, animation effects, or a browser with a WebGL-rendered moving object, you cannot reliably frame-sync it for screenshot purposes. I tried to run video in a WPF CefSharp app and the performance (perceived and measured) was abysmal on every (even high-end) computer I could find.

**You can try to port your application into WinForms** to benefit from constant frame rates. In WinForms, you would have to grab screenshots of the form or of the browser control which is messy but should be doable.